# Check if Variable is 2 less than another Variable

Tags: php, html, css, loops, for-loop

I am looping through some data and printing for every row. I do the same thing for every row except on the last one before the for loop is satisfied I want to omit one of the things I print. Here is the code I'm using.

```
$i = 5;    

for($i=0; $i < $rsc; $i++) {


    print("<div><p>Date</p></div><div><p>My Name</p></div>");
    print("<div><p>Comment</p></div>");

    //This next piece should not print on the last run through.

    if(It's not the last one){
    print("<div><p> My Section Break</p></div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, I'm confused; what was the question again? :)

Comment: Question was answered. Waiting the 10 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i < $rsc; $i++) {


    print("<div><p>Date</p></div><div><p>My Name</p></div>");
    print("<div><p>Comment</p></div>");

    //This next piece should not print on the last run through.

    if($i!=$rsc-1){
    print("<div><p> My Section Break</p></div>");
    }
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Perfect, should have known that.

Comment: Or `$i < ($rsc - 1)` :) It is a good idea to use relational expressions rather than check for (in)equality. Nice answer, though. +1